# Only first constructor showing up in javadoc (run from eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Why is only the first constructor showing up in the javadoc?

Code excerpt:

```
/**
 * Returns a <code>Config</code> object resulting from parsing a
 * configuration file.
 * 
 * @param p a <code>Path</code> object representing the configuration file.
 */
public Config(Path p) {
    ...code elided here...
}

/**
 * Returns a <code>Config</code> object resulting from parsing a
 * configuration file.
 * 
 * @param filename a <code>String</code> naming the configuration file.
 */
public Config(String filename) {
    this(Paths.get(filename));
}
```

Javadoc excerpt:

[image: There can be only one]

*(similarly only the one shows up in the "Constructor Detail" as well)*

Details for posterity: OS X 10.8.5, Eclipse EE Juno SR2, Java 1.7.0_72(*but see accepted answer*)

Comment: how are yo generating the java doc...???

Comment: I used your code and got both constructors in the Javadoc. Used Eclipse (Java EE IDE) version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). Release of Java was jdk1.8.0_66. What sort of results do you get if you run the javadoc.exe from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue with **1.6.0_21**, using `javadoc` command-line tool directly. It, understandably, complains that `package java.nio.file does not exist` buts still manages to create the files (with only one of your constructors).

It looks like you're using a 1.6 (or older) `javadoc` tool to generate docs for 1.7+ sources (this would also explain why your screenshot looks kinda ... 'old')

Comment: This was it.  The javadoc command in Eclipse was still pointing at the 1.6JDK's javadoc.  Changing that to the 1.7 one resulted in correct output.